# Pandas Filter dataframe according to working days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, filter

I want to filter a df with respect to working days.The df is:

```
name     date
aaa    12/06/2021
bbb    11/06/2021
ccc    10/06/2021
zzz    15/06/2021
ddd    13/06/2021
eee    10/05/2021
fff    01/06/2021
ggg    10/05/2021
hhh    13/06/2021
iii    14/06/2021
nnn    15/06/2021
jjj    15/06/2021
```

Now for everday process i want all the rows before two working days that means 13/06/2021 will not be included as it was a Sunday.I used

```
new_date = dt.date.today()-pd.Timedelta(2, unit='d')
new_date = pd.to_datetime(new_date)
new_df = df[df['date'] < new_date]
```

Output should be

```
name     date
aaa    12/06/2021
bbb    11/06/2021
ccc    10/06/2021
eee    10/05/2021
fff    01/06/2021
ggg    10/05/2021
```

but it is giving me sunday also ie 13/06/2021.Can anyone help me out here please

Comment: How looks expected ouput?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If need exlude only Sundays use [`offsets.CustomBusinessDay`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)

offset = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(2, weekmask='Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat')
new_date = pd.to_datetime('today').normalize() - offset
print (new_date)
2021-06-12 00:00:00

new_df = df[df['date'] <= new_date]
print (new_df)
  name       date
0  aaa 2021-06-12
1  bbb 2021-06-11
2  ccc 2021-06-10
5  eee 2021-05-10
6  fff 2021-06-01
7  ggg 2021-05-10
```

Comment: its working but giving me 2021-06-12 01:13:23.847682....I want just 2021-06-12 and even after
 new_date = pd.to_datetime(new_date)   
it is not coming as such

Comment: @naina - Anwer was eedited with `normalize`

Comment: Hey can you help me in thi     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68016966/joining-and-comparing-values-of-one-df-with-first-value-of-another-pandas